# Shiny Radiobuttons forwarding a vector

Tags: r, vector, shiny, radio-button

I'm experiencing another issue, that I'm obviously not able to solve on my own.

I'm looking for a way to pass a vector as a result of a choice by radiobutton or something similar.

```
if(!require(shiny)){
  install.packages("shiny")
  require(shiny)
}

if(!require(tidyverse)){
  install.packages("tidyverse")
  require(tidyverse)
}

if(!require(lubridate)){
  install.packages("lubridate")
  require(lubridate)
}


prodpromonat <- tibble(prodmonat= as.Date(c("2008-11-01", "2008-12-01", "2009-01-01", "2009-02-01", "2009-03-01")), n = c(1769, 3248, 3257, 2923, 3260))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

    fluidRow(
      sliderInput(
        "zeitraum",
        "Produktionszeitraum",
        min = min(prodpromonat$prodmonat),
        max = max(prodpromonat$prodmonat),
        value = c(max(prodpromonat$prodmonat)-30, max(prodpromonat$prodmonat))
      )
    ),

    fluidRow(
      radioButtons(
        "farbe",
        "Farbschema",
        choices = c("grau", "rot-grün", "blau-grau", "schwarz-weiß"),
        selected = "grau"
      )
    )
  ),

mainPanel(
  tabPanel(
    title = "produktion" ,
    plotOutput(
      outputId = "produktionsmenge"
    )
  )
)))

server <- function(input, output, session){

farbeninput <- reactive({
  switch(input$farbe,
         "grau" = c("#808080", "#808080"),
         "rot-grün" = c("#B22222", "#006400"),
         "blau-grau" = c("#1E90FF", "#696969"),
         "schwarz-weiß" = c("#000000", "FFFFF0")
  )
})

data <- reactive({
  df <- filter_produktionsmenge()
})

filter_produktionsmenge <- reactive({
  min <- filter(prodpromonat, prodmonat >= floor_date(input$zeitraum[1], "month"))
  max <- filter(prodpromonat, prodmonat <= floor_date(input$zeitraum[2], "month"))
  semi_join(min, max, by = "prodmonat")
})

output$produktionsmenge <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(data(), aes(prodmonat, n)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill = factor(as.numeric(month(prodmonat) %% 2 == 0)))) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=rep(c("#000000", "#008080"))) +
    xlab("Produktionsmonat") +
    ylab("Anzahl produzierter Karosserien") +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So I basically want to replace the vector in the `scale_fill_manual` values by a vector that is forwarded by the radiobuttons.

I tried to assign the vector as a result directly to the radiobutton input, which did not work.

Then I came up with the idea to use a switch case. However, when replacing the vector in the `scale_fill_manual` by the reactive switch input it shows the Error "attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'". I'm not sure, where this error comes from and what to do to avoid it. Hopefully you can help?

I hope you'll forgive me for not translating the German words and abbreviations in the code :)

Comment: what did you `scale_fill_manual` look like with the reactive object?

Comment: `scale_fill_manual(values=rep(farbeninput))` i just pasted the name of the switch for the vector...

Comment: Would you add `()` to the reactive object, please?

Comment: yep, this works perfectly. thank you so much!

Comment: you got it! happy coding